# Visual studio strange compilation errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Recently after migrating to new desktop, my C# project in visual studio (both in 15 &17) is throwing compilation errors with 
"Could not copy the file XX because it was not found".

These files are in no way related to the project and the path is also different. Any idea of what might be causing this error?

[image]

Comment: Do you have these files referenced in your project file?

Comment: Nope, this has nothing to do with my projects.

Comment: These files are referenced somewhere, but they don't exist.  That's literally what the error is.  Have you viewed the project file in a text editor and searched for these file names?

Comment: @Seano666 I checked it , there are no reference to these files, meanwhile it is compiling fine in another machine, that machine also doesn't have any of the files mentioned. This error happens in this particular machine only. the above files are no way related to this project.